# Infinite for loop using continue

Tags: c++, for-loop, infinite-loop, continue

I'm writing a code that will run through each bin in a histogram and check if there are any non zero bins. If there are, it throws out an error message. My issue is, I want it to skip a bin because this bin should not be empty, but check all the other bins.

Only thing is this is creating an infinite loop. Here's my code

```
Int_t y;

for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    y = hist - > GetBinContent(i)

    if (i = 1) continue;
    else if (y != 0) {
        std: cout << * * * * * ERROR * * * * * << std: endl;
        break;
    }

}
```

What's happening is it evaluates it for `i = 0`, skips `i = 1`, and then hits `i = 2` and just continually evaluates that over and over again. If I take out the "if (i=1) continue;" line then it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to remember what `=` and `==` do!

Comment: You need to enable more warnings on your compiler. With gcc turn on -Wall, with clang turn on -Weverything (and then turn off the warnings that are useless for you, like -Wc++98-compat), on Visual Studio turn the warning level up to level 4 with /W4. With any of these the compiler will catch this error and warn about it: gcc says "warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value"; clang says "warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses"; VS says "Warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression".

Comment: For the record, `-Wall` doesn't remotely show all warnings. You need to manually enable a bunch of them for `gcc`. That's why `-Weverything` is Wonderful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
if (i==1) continue;
```

`i=1` mean you assign `1` to `i`. `=` means assign and `==` mean comparing .

In your code the value of `i` will always be `1`  as you are using `i=1`

Answer (score 2):

When you have errors with loops, it sometimes helps to run it in debug mode with a breakpoint in the loop or to put a print statement inside. Your error comes from the line:
    `if (i=1) continue;` . The segment `i=1` sets i to be one and returns the value of i, which is interpreted as true (since it is non-zero). Then it goes to the next iteration, where it will once again set i to one. What you likely meant was `if (i==1) continue;` . This performs the comparison operator, which is what you intended.